# Proof of a corollary of the Noether normalisation lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I can't understand the proof of a corollary of the Noether normalisation lemma in *Undergraduate algebraic geometry* by Miles Reid.

> **Noether normalisation lemma** Let $k$ be an infinite field, and $A=k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Then there exists $m\leq n$ and $y_1,\cdots,y_m \in A$ such that
>
> 1. $y_1,\cdots,y_m$ are algebraically independent over $k$.
> 2. $A$ is finitely generated as $k[y_1,\dots,y_m]$-module.
>
> **Corollary** Under the hypotheses of the Noether normalisation lemma, 
>   there exist $y_1,\cdots,y_m,y_{m+1} \in A$ such that $y_1,\cdots,y_m$ satisfy the conclusion of the lemma, and in addition, the field of fractions $K$ of $A$ is generated over $k$ by $y_1,\cdots,y_m,y_{m+1}$.

In the proof of the corollary, 
it is first proven that $y_1,\cdots,y_m$ can be chosen so that $K$ is a finite separable extension of $k(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$. And there exists $y_{m+1} \in K$ such that $K= k(y_1,\cdots,y_m,y_{m+1})$. I can understand this part. Then,

> $y_{m+1}$ can be taken as a linear combination of $x_i$ with coefficients in $k[y_1,\cdots,y_m]$

Why is that ?

Comment: Note that the corollary is not true without additional hypothesis. In the proof, when it is said that $K$ is a finite separable extension of $k(y_1,\dots, y_m)$, this implies that $K\otimes_k \bar{k}$ is reduced, so $A\otimes_k \bar{k}$ is reduced. In the corollary, this condition is therefore necessary (actually sufficient).

Comment: @Cantlog : There is an _addendum_ between the lemma and the corollary saying "under the condition of the lemma, if furthermore $k$ is algebraiccaly closed, and $A$ is an integral domain with field of fractions $K$ then ...". So, they may be the additional conditions.

Comment: Ah, then the statement is correct.